# Question about Continuity of Characteristic Function

Tags: real-analysis, characteristic-functions

Is the function $f_n= \chi_{[\frac{j}{2^k} , \frac{j+1}{2^k}]}$, where $n=2^k+j$ with $0 \leq 2^k$, continuous on the interval $[0,1]$? I have no intuition regarding how this function looks geometrically and also why we have that $\int^{1}_{0}|f_n|=2^{-k}$ for $2^k\leq n<2^{k+1}$.

Do you have any tips as to how to think about this kind of function, especially how to integrate this kind of function with the Riemann Integral, if possible? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks 1 on some interval and 0 outside that interval. So definitely not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$f_n(x)=1$ for $x \in [\frac{j}{2^k} , \frac{j+1}{2^k}]$ and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x \in [0,1] \setminus [\frac{j}{2^k} , \frac{j+1}{2^k}]$.

$f_n$ is not continuous at $\frac{j}{2^k}$ and at $\frac{j+1}{2^k}$

Furthermore $\int^{1}_{0}|f_n| dx=\int^{1}_{0}f_n dx=\int^{\frac{j+1}{2^k}}_{\frac{j}{2^k}}1 dx=\frac{j+1}{2^k}-\frac{j}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2^k}$.

Comment: If you do not mind me asking, is there any way to modify this function into a continuous one but such that the integral still tends to 0?

Comment: For example by connecting the endpoints to the value 0 using a linear function somehow.

Comment: @GabyBoyAnalysis that's the sort of question that is interesting enough (since you don't know the answer) and also not hard to compute, so I encourage you to try for yourself. The function you are asking about is piecewise linear. Surely you know how to integrate linear functions and discover the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Some related graphs, in the name of 'geometric intuition'-

([Interactive graph with adjustable parameters $j,k$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6q14alhhjx))
[image]

The top two graphs are continuous, the bottom two graphs correspond to the function in your question. Essentially, the function in the question is the result of rescaling and translating the simpler function $\chi_{[0,1]}$. The rescaling has a linear effect on the area, while translation has no effect.